# Keep UITableView scrolled to bottom as new rows are added

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Part of an app I'm working on involves a messaging interface which I'm trying to make similar to the iOS Messages app's interface. When new messages are received or sent, I'd like the table view to scroll down and display the insertion animation.

So far, I've essentially done this:

```
- (void)didReceiveNewMessage:(...) {
    [messages addObject:...];                            // add the new message to an array
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath ...];       // find out where the new cell goes
    [tableView insertRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath ...];   // animate the insertion of the new message
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath ...]; // do the scrolling
}
```

This works if messages are coming in slowly. However, if I send myself a bunch of messages really quickly, I've noticed the table view will "become confused."

For example, if I quickly send the messages 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, the table view will animate the insertion of 1, 2, 3, and 4, and then just stop scrolling. If I actually scroll the table view down manually, I can see 5 and 6 below. Anyone know of a better way to do this?

I did try `setContentOffset:` to scroll the table view, but this had the same effect.

Comment: are you calling this method asynchronously?

Comment: Try calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath fist and then insertRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: If you find out that this is a synchronization issue, then add [tableView peformSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)]; However, I am not sure wether reloadData would actually scroll back to position 1 or 0 repectively.

Comment: @Armaan No, this is all happening on the main thread right now.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I don't think I get what you're saying... if I switched those lines it would be trying to scroll to an index path that doesn't yet exist in the table.

Comment: why manually scrolling needed when there is built in animation property of insertRowAtIndexPath just give the animation parameter value with UITableViewRowAnimationBottom

Comment: Well, yes, switching alone would not help. You would have to scroll to that position -1. :) On the other hand Armaan is right. insertRowsAtIndexPaths should do the trick. And it works with multiple rows in one go, if you want.

Comment: `UITableViewRowAnimationBottom` just inserts the row from the bottom; it has nothing to do with the scroll position of the table view after the insertion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The underlying issue here is that I was lazy and used `CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation` instead of manually computing the new frames, because I forgot that when the `transform` property is changed frames become "undefined" according to Apple documentation.

It ended up working okay until lots of messages came in at which point the table view's frame would get messed up and offset somehow which would cause the bottom of the table view to be displayed slightly lower than it should've been.

Lesson learned: Don't mix frame computations and transformations in one animation. Either keep everything in terms of frames, or keep everything in terms of transformations and use `center` + `bounds`.